# How to get Chargify Webhook Response in .Net

Tags: webhooks, chargify

I have already configure webhook url in chargify. This url is for webapi.

So i'm handling all events in webapi. But I want to know that how can we get the request parameter from chargify. If anyone have an example, would you please give me.

Below is the request from the chargify webhook's one event

you can get the below link for the webhook sending request for the events.
https://docs.chargify.com/webhooks#signup-success-payload

Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution from above but it didn't work for me (probably because it's a 2015 solution and Chargify has made a few changes in the time).

What worked for me was:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult Test([FromForm] RequestObject request)
```

If we will use `RequestObject` with **ModelBinding**, we have to create the data structure of the objects and variables we want to use.

For instance, for the `signup_success` event, the data structure for the objects Product, Customer and Customer Reference will be:

```
public class RequestObject 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public Subscription subscription { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public long id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's submitted to the webhook url as form-parameters, so in MVC your signature would look similar to the following:

```
public ActionResult ReceiveWebhook(FormCollection webhookPayload, string signature_hmac_sha_256)
```

The parameter `signature_hmac_sha_256` is included in the query string, so it's passed here.

You could then run different logic by using the `event`:

```
var eventName = webhookPayload["event"];
```